# How to build my project using Maven in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, filewriter, artifact

Simply I've have 3 classes in my JavaAppX,

1-Content Reader, that reads a text file and store its content into an arraylist of strings.

```
public class ContentReader {

public ArrayList<String> readInput(String filename) {
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null)

                strings.add(line);
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Error : "+error.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        return strings;
            }

    }
}
```

2-Content Writer, that takes the arraylist of strings from Content Reader and copies its content into another file (file2.bat).

```
public class ContentWriter {

public void createFile (String filename){
    ContentReader reader = new ContentReader();
    ArrayList<String> strings;
    strings = reader.readInput(filename);
    System.out.println("Array Size = "+strings.size());
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("file2.bat");
        file.createNewFile();
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        for (String string : strings){
            fileWriter.write(string+"\n");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error){
        System.out.println("Error : "+error.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (fileWriter != null)
                fileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (Exception error){
            System.out.println("Error : "+error.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

3-Main, that creates an instance object of Content writer, and executes file2.bat.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    ContentWriter contentWriter = new ContentWriter();
    contentWriter.createFile("file.txt");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime.exec("file2.bat");
    } catch (Exception error){
        System.out.println("Error : "+error.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The problem is :

1-After building this project into Artifact Jar, it doesn't read file.txt and throws an exception as it can't find it.

2-What I want is to include the file.txt into Jar and be able to read it, to continue its process.

3-Someone has advised to build this project into Maven, really, that process was too complex for a beginner, and I followed up some articles, and building process with involving into configuring POM.xml and some other things, but after doing what they told me to do, I've got some errors upon building.

Comment: What are those errors that you got upon building using maven?

Comment: These are at least two different questions. If you want to embed a file into a jar, read about resources. For Maven, read an introductory article, write a POM and try to run Maven. If you have errors you don't understand, come back with them.

Comment: You can't write files from the classpath jar, it has to be next to the jar.

Comment: If it next to it, okay, it can be read, but what If you want to embed your entire project files into a single jar.